# How to include a .js file in PL/SQL on Oracle10gXE

Tags: javascript, oracle, plsql, httpd.conf

again. I'm making a PL/SQL generated HTML5 web page. It's running a Oracle 10g XE server. Okay, now when the setup is clear, my problem - I need to include a Java Script file in the page. Simply

```
    HTP.P('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ScriptFileName.js"></script>');
```

Doesn't work of course. So i created a folder object and granted read,write to PUBLIC. Then changed the string to match the newly created object, instead of path. Still doesn't work. I know, i can write

```
    HTP.P(<script type="text/javascript"> MY JAVA SCRIPT HERE</script>);
```

And i've done so with other scripts(Even had to write CSS this way). But this time this will not work. Reason being - the JavaScript i'm trying to run was normalized(or rather unnormalized), so it's written all in one line. And there is a lot of it too. I tried to reverse it to normal, but faild many a time.

So, I went online and searched for a solution. Found one. It seem's that this include should go not to the page, but to server config. Makes sense, since PL/SQL is server sided. But when i went looking for the usual httpd.conf, it's nowhere to be found in Database directory.So i went online again, result - NOT A WORD OF WHERE THE HELL ARE HTTP SERVER CONFIGS IN 10gXE IN ANY ORACLE MANUALS. Searched some forums - exactly 1 person asked where httpd.conf in XE is, and didn't get an answer. Please, help. I'm desperate.

P.S. I don't use APEX. I don't get that mumbo-jumbo. So i write in Notepad and run the scripts in SQL line.

Comment: I can't read your question. How can i answered it?

Comment: "P.S. I don't use APEX. I don't get that mumbo-jumbo. So i write in Notepad and run the scripts in SQL line."  Right; that'll simplify things :-)

Comment: Thanks to whoever edited this, i can't input codes for some reason 4 spaces or not, they just don't show, why isn't there a code tag?

Comment: I edited it - just put a blank line above and below the indented code.  There is no code tag because this site uses a different syntax; however there is a "code" button with an icon like "{}" that does the job on selected text.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I tried selecting code and pressing code button(it usualy works this way), but it only gave an explanation(which either didn't work, or didn't show on preview)

Comment: So... no one? Not one person at all knows the answer to my question? Or is it truly imposible?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, XE has its own built in HTTP server called the 'Embedded PL/SQL Gateway' or EPG. But you don't HAVE to use that. You can use an Oracle HTTP Server with the mod_plsql plugin. Or you can use the Apex listener.

The question is on what server is "ScriptFileName.js" ?

1. Is it a flat file on the database server ? If so, you'll need to use the Oracle HTTP Server (or Apache or similar) to serve it. The database is pretty much unaware of files on its server and the EPG can't deliver them. [At least not in any practical sense, you could do weird things with chicken entrails and UTL_FILE, but you don't want to go there.]
2. Is it a file stored in the database ? That sounds exotic, but it is pretty much how all the CSS, images etc are served up through the EPG. The best explanation on how to get files in and out of there is by [Dietmar](http://daust.blogspot.com/2006/03/where-are-images-of-application.html)
3. Is it a file stored on a separate machine ? Often the best answer. The "src=" directive will be read by the end users browser. That will do an HTTP get to the URL. It doesn't have to be a URL on the same domain/host as the rest of the page.